# easing the gradle build process in deploying spring boot and angular js application

Tags: angularjs, gradle, build, spring-boot, gulp

I am working on gradle based spring boot and angularjs project. I have all my angularjs code in `static` folder which is committed to Git. We need to deploy it into a server which does not have access to internet. So I have generated `dist` contents using `gulp serve:dist` and replaced the contents in the `static` folder with the contents of `dist` folder. Then I have generated jar file and deployed in server.

So it is becoming manually cumbersome every time to replace the contents of `static` folder with the contents of `dist` generating jar file then removing the `dist` folder contents from `static` folder and then replacing it with original angular js code.

Is there any possibility to generate the jar file directly using the contents from `dist` folder instead using the contents in `static` folder?

I am not sure whether I made the problem clear or not. Please update me if you need any further clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Spring Boot with standalone JAR deployment, you just need to output front-end assets into `src/main/resources/static` and Spring Boot will serve them via embedded container.

You can use [Gradle Gulp Plugin](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.moowork.gulp/0.11) to execute Gulp build as task within main Gradle build.

Reaction on comment:

Mentioned static folder of course contains only assets you intend to serve by Spring Boot. It wouldn't contain code or anything else. You can have your code in e.g. `[projectRoot]/jsSrc`. Just Gulp needs to know where to find these files.

We are using such directory structure without any problems (with CI build running on every commit). If manual action is needed to build project, your build is fundamentally broken. In this case your issue is misplaced JS source files.

Comment: That is what I am doing now. In Static folder I am keeping the front-end assets output (i.e., dist folder contents - minified files) and then making a jar build. But that is place where we keep actual angularjs code files also for git commit. Before making jar build I am removing the actual angularjs code files, keeping the dist contents and making jar build. Then remvoing these dist contents from static folder and keeping actual angularjs code files and committing to git. Sorry, I don't follow how your solution solves the problem that  I have reported.